# Разбор регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть необходимость достраивать строку до "полного вида". Думал сделать это через регулярное выражение.

В тексте находится фрагмент примерно такого вида: 1-1-1-1, нужно его при помощи регулярного выражения хочу выделить найти его, после каждую группу разделенную спецсимволом "-" нужно дополнить другими цифрами.

Например:

- Входная строка: `"1-1-1-1"`
- Регулярное выражение: `"(?<code>(\d?\d?)-(\d?\d?\d)-(\d)-(\d?\d?\d?\d))"`

Данная строка удовлетворяет регулярному выражению и в ней выделяются 5 групп: `"code", 1, 2, 3, 4`

Нужно как-то на основе регулярного выражения код привести к виду: `01-001-1-0001`

Проблема в том, что таких масок может быть несколько, как впрочем и входных значений: `11-2-3-44` должно стать: `11-002-3-0044`

Думал может можно как-то узнать, какая часть регулярного выражения сработала на какой фрагмент текста и данный фрагмент на основе синтаксиса регулярного выражения достроить?

Или вообще не в ту сторону смотрю и нужно как-то по другому это все делать?

**Дополнение:**

Регулярные выражения это мое решение выдернуть фрагмент из текста.

Допустим текст содержит следующие символы:

```
"1-1-1-1 ололо 12-34-222-1 олололо 12.23-34.5"
```

Для выдёргивания нужных фрагментов реализованы несколько масок:

```
"\d{1,2}-\d{1,3}-\d-\d{1,4}"
"\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,4}-\d"
"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,5}"
```

Прогоняя текст последовательно по данным маскам, мне нужно заменить выдернутые фрагменты на следующие, достраивая группы ведущими нулями:

```
"01-001-1-0004 ололо 12-34-0222-1 олололо 12.23-34.00005"
```

Comment: У вас всегда 4 блока цифр в строке? Нужно ли вообще проверять строку с помощью регулярного выражения? Может, разбить строку на части с помощью `-`, а потом добавить нули? Кстати, у вас тут `(\d?\d?)`, значит ли это, что строка может выглядеть как `-1-1-1`?

Comment: Универсальное выражение: `(\d{1,}){1,}?(?-)`

Comment: А что нужно сделать-то? Найти и заменить во входной строке?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew в рамках одного регулярного выражения - да. Но таких регулярных выражений несколько и в каждом может отличаться как количество групп и количество знаков в каждой группе, так и разделители групп (где-то может точка, где-то тире, где-то пробел)

Comment: @Birdy не пойдет открытые группы делать. Во-первых ограничение по количеству символов должно быть: 1 и не более 3 или 1 и не более 2, во вторых количество групп также должно быть ограничено, чтобы числа для 7 групп не попадали в выборку (да я в этой регулярке забыл указать ограничения

Comment: @Андрей нужно найти и заменить, да. Но я не знаю изначально сколько символов нужно мне достроить и для какой группы.

Comment: @pincher1519, а когда вы это узнаете?

Comment: @Андрей, когда получаю от источника само регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь перегрузкой `Regex.Replace`, принимающей `MatchEvaluator`:

```
string pattern = @"(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,3})-(\d)-(\d{1,4})";
string s = @"1-1-1-1 olololo 2-3-4-5";
string r = Regex.Replace(s, pattern,
    m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(2, '0')}-{m.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(3, '0')}-{m.Groups[3].Value.PadLeft(1, '0')}-{m.Groups[4].Value.PadLeft(4, '0')}");
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Выведет:

> 01-001-1-0001 olololo 02-003-4-0005

Comment: Хороший вариант. А можно как-то не завязываться на value.PadLeft? если был бы универсальный вариант 1. - одна регулярка, это то что ищем, и 2. регулярка, это на что заменяем, без использования дополнительной функции. Получилось бы просто пройти в цикле по всем "маскам" и выполнить замену на выражение соответствующее данной "маске".

Comment: Я вас не понимаю

Comment: У Вас в примере выражение замены узкоспециализировано под конкретное регулярное выражение. У меня несколько регулярных выражений, которые будут храниться отдельно от программы. Если бы можно было написать пару: "Ключ" -"Значение", при помощи которого произвести такие манипуляции замены - это было бы 100% решением мой проблемы. В данном случае, я могу записать "ключ" - "(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,3})-(\d)-(\d{1,4})", а использовать "значение" для замены "{m.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(2, '0')}..."  не могу.

Comment: Правильное значение выходной строки вы в виде регулярки получаете? приведите пример

Comment: я пытаюсь при помощи регулярки выдернуть фрагмент текста и в нем "достроить" нужные символы до полной группы. Мое решение было делать это при помощи регулярки, ибо писать парсер самому это жутко кривое что-то получится. Вы подсказали, что это можно сделать через замену через регулярное выражение, но используются методы, которые я не могу сохранить как пару в текстовом документе.

Comment: Простите, но вы очень косноязычно пишете, я вас очень плохо понимаю. Вы можете просто предоставить пример входных данных? Что вам приходит на вход? Как задаются длины блоков "полного вида"?

Comment: я попробовал добавить примеры в сам вопрос в конце.

Comment: "на следующие" - на какие? Как вы определили, что вам нужно именно 2, 3, 1, 4 знака в `01-001-1-0004`?

Comment: в регулярке указываю количество максимальных знаков. Именно для данной регулярки я знаю сколько знаков должно быть в каждой группе. Группы достраиваются нулями до максимально возможного.

Comment: Вы регулярку как-то динамически собираете что ли? Можно, конечно, последовательно дописывать в каждую группу ведущий ноль пока выражение всё еще удовлетворяет регулярке, но мне это решение не очень нравится

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70898/discussion-between-pincher1519-and-).

Comment: нет же. Регулярку я сам строю, но код обрабатывающий это регулярное выражение ничего не знает, как и что ему нужно достраивать. Ему просто будет передаваться сама регулярка, текст и какие-нибудь другие текстовые параметры. На основе этого нужно как-то достроить группы.

Comment: Ну а сделать чтобы передавались длины выходных блоков вы не можете? Вместе или вместо регулярки

Comment: Я пока сделал имена групп в имени которых содержится номер группы и количество символов. Но это выглядит очень не очень. `(?gr<1_2>\d{1,2})-(?<gr_2_3>\d{1,3})-(?<gr_3_5>\d{1,5})`

Comment: Что мешает также передать нормальные числовые длины блоков?

Comment: всеравно через 1 параметр передавать в виде склеенной строки. Повторюсь, можно передать только 3 параметра в виде текста.